# Need the calendar web part to display recurring items as individual items

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-calendar, ootb

I have a calendar OOTB webpart in use, and for the most part it works fine, but in the All items view, it would be helpful to see recurring items that occur every week to show up like the one of kind events.  Right now, they just appear one time in the list as in the image attached.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use the 'Current Events' view instead? that splits recurring events into individual items.

Answer (score 0):

As @Robin said you can use 'Current Events' view to get recurrence events splitted  but you will not find Start Time and End Time columns there to set the filter conditions for the Current Events View.

If you are looking for web parts where you can set upcoming events and all and you wanted to display filtered event instances from the recurrence event then you have to create visual web part and using dll from the following code you can expand recurrence events.

https://github.com/ronnieholm/SPCalendarRecurrenceExpander